# Two Factor Authentication via Email in Twilio

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, authy

By looking over the DOCS of Twilio, the Twilio has started two factor authentication codes to be sent in Email too. But I cannot find any implementation of this using Authy API.

I am using Python, and currently sending SMS based 2FA codes to phones using below code:

```
from authy.api import AuthyApiClient
AuthyApiClient(AUTH_SECRET_KEY).phones.verification_start(PHONE_NUMBER, COUNTRY_CODE)
```

I want to give flexibility to my user, to either OPT for SMS or EMail based OTP, not both. I have already integrated my SendGrid Account to Twilio. Any help on code part, I didn't find any implemented code using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can check out [the documentation for sending email verification through Authy with SendGrid here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/email).